# I'm a painter who like or likes

Tags: grammar

I'm confused about this one.
After 'who' should the verb be 'like' or 'likes'?

Comment: See also https://www.englishforums.com/English/ItIsIWhoIsOrItIsIWhoAm/xzkgn/post.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm a painter who likes painting.

The singular subject of the sentence--I--requires a singular verb.

If, however, the subject of the sentence is plural, the sentence would need a plural verb, as in

> We are painters who like painting.

Comment: Shouldn't "like" agree with "painter", not with "I"?

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. But off-topic, would 'that' instead of  'who' be grammatically correct? as in "I'm a painter that likes..."

Comment: Yes and no? The singular subject of the sentence--I--has the singular verb *am*. But the singular noun of the phrase--painter--requires the third-person singular verb *likes*.

Comment: @reda: I'd stick with "who." A person isn't a "that" but a "who." Don